# What are arguments to a monad bind operation formally called?

Tags: haskell, naming-conventions

For example, in the list monad bind operation:

```
xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)
```

What is the argument f called? A binder? mapper? transformer?

Comment: Wouldn't be surprised if there isn't one.. It's a continuation in some sense I suppose.

Comment: You could call it the Kleisli arrow.

Comment: Out of curiosity I checked the original Wadler papers too see if he intended for any interesting names. No, seems like he just calls it a function or a "computation" occasionally when talking about IO.

Comment: Klesili arrow, and `<=<` is their composition. (in that sense, `>>=` is only a by-product of what this really is about)

Comment: `f` can be seen as "monadic value constructor": if we call `:: m a` "monadic values", then `:: a -> m b` are constructors of such. And if we call `:: m a` "computations", then `:: a -> m b` are "computation constructors".

Comment: Often `k` is used where you have `f` to (believe it or not) stand for continuation. See (http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/lectures/12-monads.html)

Comment: I would also call it the "continuation".  The only reason I haven't written this up as an answer is because @jozefg or Yofe should do so and claim the upvotes!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to be glib, but the argument is called `f`, since depending on what it does, one of any number of names could be applicable. What matters, simply, is its type `a -> m b` for your `Monad` instance `m`. As David Yong's comment notes, we can describe things of that form as an "arrow (or morphism) in the Kleisli category of `m`".

Answer (score -1):

According to Wiki, I quote .. "programmable semicolons" or "assembly lines".

A type with a monad structure defines what it means to chain operations,
so "assembly line" probably best describes it.